# Why am I not able to deploy ERC721 contract to Avalanche Fuji?

Tags: remix, erc-721, avalanche, fuji

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@5.0.0/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract NFTERC721 is ERC721 {
    uint256 private _nextTokenId;

    constructor()
        ERC721("NFTERC721", "NFT721")
    {}

    function safeMint(address to) public {
        uint256 tokenId = _nextTokenId++;
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }
}
```

This is the token contract code . I am trying to deploy this contract on Avalanche Fuji testnet , but I get an error . ( Refer the image attached )
[image]

why is the contract not getting deployed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solidity 0.8.20 introduced the `PUSH0(0x5f)` opcode which is only supported on the ETH mainnet and not on any other chains. That's why other chains can't find the PUSH0(0x5f) opcode and throw this error.

Consider either using 0.8.19 for other chains, or use a different EVM version, other than shanghai.

This should solve your problem.

If you want to learn more about PUSH0 opcode you can check this small article which explains it pretty well. https://www.zaryabs.com/push0-opcode/

Comment: even after using 0.8.19 for the Solidity version , the problem does not get solved . It is because I am importing Openzeppelin contracts v5 ( these contracts are using solidity v0.8.20 . Is it ok to use Openzeppelin contacts v4.7.3 ( these contracts use solidity ^0.8.0 ) ?

Comment: Yup, that's totally okay to use. It's all up to your needs. All versions of OZ contracts are fine. But also try to use a different compiler version, just to see if that's more easy for you.  Either way is fine, whatever suits you.

Comment: okay bro , thanks !